# How do I pass control to another command-line program

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have two related programs, one is interactive and the other is not. Both can be run from the command-line. The interactive program maintains parameters and on completion optionally writes the parameters to file. It also optionally allows the non-interactive program to run, and if so it "passes" the parameters to the non-interactive program (via Process.start()) and displays the output from the non-interactive program.

The non-interactive program can also be run from the command-line. It reads the parameters from file and displays them. It then optionally provides for a) processing using the parameters, b) termination, or c) loading the program that maintains the parameters.

What I would like to be able to do for "c" is "simply" pass control to the interactive program and terminate the non-interactive program. The interactive program would then take over and maintain the parameters and allow running of the non-interactive program.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: did you try to simply invoke main method of non-interactive program?

Comment: Is this a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18701856/638061? For that question, you got some fairly good advice on how to go about dealing with your two related programs. Since you have further issues, why not post some actual code? Let us see what you've been trying out so that we can have something concrete to work with.

Comment: No, it's not a repeat. In this case, I want to pass control completely to another process (a dart program in this case). I don't want to interact with it at all. I want to terminate the current program and run the other program instead.